# Deeplink in facebook app page in iOS not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, deep-linking

I have an app page in facebook. I have used `Call to action` feature to create `Use app` button in my app page.

[image]

[image]

I have an app in iOS. What I wanted to achieve is that when ever a user clicks on the `Use app` button from his iOS device (Safari or Facebook app) He/She should be navigated to the AppStore or App(if app is already installed).

What I get now is, whenever I click on the `Use app` button from iOS I get navigated to my website.

Anyone got ideas to fix it?

Comment: Why `android` tag here?

Comment: Why is Android tagged.

Comment: @Razgriz , @M D Same happens with android app too

Comment: @VinoyAlexander But you have to mention about android in your question too. Where it is?

Comment: Hi @vinoy alexander , could you resolve this issue, I have same issue that use app button always opens app download link even app is installed in iOS?

Comment: Hi @ScorpianAlive , Have you checked the App link you have given in your app's info.plist?

Comment: I was having a similar problem - answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32250897/ios-app-deeplink-for-facebook-call-to-action-nothing-happens